# set a path to move_base

Tags: navigation, move-base, 3d-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
In order to do my own 3D navigation I would like to set a path to move_base.

I explain what i am doing:

- I generate 3 2d map
- Use each of these 3d map for generated a plan ( with make_plan)

But now i want to check if one path is good in each 2d maps.

So i was thinking to check this with the move_base but I find nothing to load a path. (I could maybe change the move_base code to subscribe to a topic and use the received path, but it sound complicated )

Is there a way to load a path in the move_base ? Or someone have an idea how could i do that?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188015/set-a-path-to-move_base/) by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 312 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Assuming that you implemented a plugin of BaseGlobalPlanner to plan your paths, you can just publish the plan to topic and then you can see the results in rviz.
You just need to do

```
ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~/" + name);   
plan_pub_ = private_nh.advertise<nav_msgs::Path>("plan", 1);
```

And then implement a method to fill a nav_msgs::Path msg and publish it.

---

Originally posted by [mateus03](https://answers.ros.org/users/18781/mateus03/) with karma: 73 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2014-07-29**:
thank you i will see how to write a plugin to BaseGlobalPlanner.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mike Phillips did some great work on this during his internship at Willow Garage, and published the software as a ROS package: http://wiki.ros.org/3d_navigation

The wiki page doesn't mention it, but I believe internally he's doing collision checks against several 2D maps as a shortcut to full 3D collision checking. The paper linked from the wiki page goes into much greater detail about this.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2014-07-29**:
thank you for the link, but i am pretty new in ROS so I don't know how to break the package down. With which file should i start?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-29**:
I'm not familiar with the code, so I can't give you any hints there. I would probably start by reading the paper, and then contact the authors directly if you have questions about their implementation.